# How to dynamically keep elements inside their parent container when animating?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, random

I am animating divs'. The animation is very simply moving each div along x and y axis. I am randomly setting the x and y axis value using javascript. I want the animation to be bound only inside the its containing element.

But despite getting height and width using clientHeight & clientWidth in javascript. The animation is getting out the container.Animation is done using Anime.js

I have put all required code.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
//function to create div and insert it to DOM
function domDiv(count, element, className, elementId) {
    let i = 0;
    while (i != count) {
        let div1 = document.createElement(element);
        div1.setAttribute('class', className);
        document.getElementById(elementId).appendChild(div1);
        i++;
    }
}

//function to generate random numbers bounded with container's height and width
function seed(property) {
    let ranNum;
    if (property == 'H') {
        let height = document.getElementById('parent1').clientHeight;
        ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);
        console.log("H: ", height);
        console.log("ranNum ", ranNum);
        return ranNum;
    }
    else {
        let width = document.getElementById('parent1').clientWidth;
        ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);
        console.log("W: ", width);
        console.log("ranNum ", ranNum);
        return ranNum;
    }
}

//animation function, animation done using anime.js
function randomValues() {
    anime({
        targets: '#parent1 .divs1',
        translateX: function () {
            return anime.random(seed('W'), seed('W'));
        },
        translateY: function () {
            return anime.random(seed('H'), seed('H'));
        },
        scale: [
            { value: .1, easing: 'easeOutSine', duration: 500 },
            { value: 1, easing: 'easeInOutQuad', duration: 1200 }
        ],
        delay: anime.stagger(200, { grid: [14, 5], from: 'center' }),
        duration: 800,
        easing: 'easeInOutSine',
        complete: randomValues
    });
}

//execution starts from here or main control takes place below
domDiv(50, 'div', 'divs1', 'parent1');
randomValues();
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <section id="parent1"></section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#parent1 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    /* padding: 50px; */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    border: solid red 2px;
}

.divs1 {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 3vw;
    height: 3vw;
}

.divs1:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.divs1:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: `I am randomly setting the x and y axis` Wouldn't this pick the wrong x and y ?

Comment: Yes but it's within clientwidth and clientheight, which provides selected element'swidth and height. Check the code please. Correct any mistakes.

Comment: Yes the randomness is the issue, sometimes a circle is in the middle and it gets a random value higher than the rest of the available space left before going outside,You need to map the values you feed the random function, you need to take into account how much space there's on the left,right,top,bottom based on the current position and the size of the circle.

Comment: Ok I will try creating a mapping code for space available around each elements.